# Making Async AJAX calls Synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, asynchronous, synchronization

Environment: Ext-JS Frontend UI -> AJAX Calls -> Spring MVC Server/Java -> Apache CXF to MQ -> Back-end COBOL.

Based on the above environment we can not handle asynchronous AJAX calls being sent due to a limitation with the backend COBOL server. Normally we daisy chain our ajax calls. However now we need an automatic refresh mechanism on some UI pages. So if we happen to send a normal AJAX request from the UI at the same time as a refresh (AJAX) calls gets dispatched then we need to queue the two calls and make them effectively Synchronous.  Any solution would need to be generic though.

What would be the simplest way of dealing with this scenario ? Is there a simple approach of blocking the refresh call when a request has already been dispatched? Or would it be best to use an ExecutorService in the Java Server layer to handle the scenario ? Or maybe futures/promises. How would I make that work ?

Hope this make sense and any suggestions on an approach would be appreciated.

Comment: The front-end has little to do with the synchronousness of the server. You *can* do AJAX on a synchronous language (like PHP for instance) Why do you need it to be synchronous? What *exactly* are you trying to pull off here?

Comment: By "we can not handle asynchronous AJAX calls", do you mean that the UI won't know when the call has been completely processed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a queuing system like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) the flow would look like:

`Ext-JS Frontend UI -> AJAX Calls -> Spring MVC Server/Java -> Beanstalkd -> Apache CXF to MQ -> Back-end COBOL.`